# How to fix 'Incompatible shapes' error in keras?

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to make a code with *keras and tensorflow* and I want to use batch size.

you can find the code in https://github.com/aSafarpoor/vgg_vidclassification.git

and it can run with something like this:

> python main.py --net resnet34s --batch_size 1 --gpu 2,3 --lr 0.001 --warmup_ratio 0.1 --optimizer adam --epochs 4 --multiprocess 1 --loss softmax --hdim 30 --wdim 30  --frame_num 80  --aggregation_mode vlad  --vlad_cluster 4

when i set batch size==1 then it works,
but when i change it to another numbers it make an error like this:

```
Epoch 1/2
Learning rate for epoch 1 is 0.0001.

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "main.py", line 214, in <module> main()

  File "main.py", line 145, in main verbose=1)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", 
line 91, in wrapper

    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 

1418, in fit_generator

    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py", line 217, in fit_generator
class_weight=class_weight)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 
1217, in train_on_batch
outputs = self.train_function(ins)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2715, in __call__
    return self._call(inputs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2675, in _call
    fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1458, in __call__
    run_metadata_ptr)

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible 
shapes: [2,5994] vs. [6,5994]
     [[{{node 
training/Adam/gradients/loss/prediction_loss/mul_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs}}]
]
```

and I run it with different version , error was the same ; like shapes: [2] vs [6]

and the important part of error as you see is :

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible 
    shapes: [2,5994] vs. [6,5994]
         [[{{node 
  training/Adam/gradients/loss/prediction_loss/mul_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs}}]
    ]
```

about code:

at first most important parts are in src folder that is reachable in git

this part is for  trainning:
network.fit_generator(trn_gen,

```
steps_per_epoch=int(len(partition['train'])//args.batch_size),
                          epochs=args.epochs,
                          max_queue_size=10,
                          callbacks=callbacks,
                          use_multiprocessing=False,
                          workers=1,
                          verbose=1)
```

read videos like this in utils.py:

```
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
success,image = vidcap.read()
success2=success
while(success):
    image= cv2.resize(image,(dim_h,dim_w))
    sub_arr.append(image)
    success,image = vidcap.read() 
    c+=1
while(c<spec_len and success2):
    sub_arr.append(sub_arr[-1])
    c+=1

# if(len(sub_arr)>0):
big_arr=sub_arr[:spec_len]
np_arr=np.asarray(big_arr)
# print(np_arr.shape,"       GgggG")
return np_arr
```

and then make data ready:

```
trnlist, trnlb = toolkits.get_voxceleb2_datalist(args, path='../meta/voxlb2_train.txt')
vallist, vallb = toolkits.get_voxceleb2_datalist(args, path='../meta/voxlb2_val.txt')
partition = {'train': trnlist.flatten(), 'val': vallist.flatten()}
```

model function is resnet_3D_v1 in the model.py,take a look:

```
bn_axis = 3
    if mode == 'train':
        inputs = Input(shape=input_dim, name='input')
    else:
        # inputs = Input(shape=(input_dim[0], None, input_dim[-1]), name='input')
        inputs = Input(shape=input_dim, name='input')

    # ===============================================
    #            Convolution Block 1
    # ===============================================
    x1 = Conv3D(64, (1,1,1),
                kernel_initializer='orthogonal',
                use_bias=False, trainable=True,
                kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),
                padding='same',
                name='conv1_1/3x3_s1')(inputs)

    x1 = BatchNormalization(axis=bn_axis, name='conv1_1/3x3_s1/bn', trainable=True)(x1)
    x1 = Activation('relu')(x1)
    x1 = MaxPooling3D((1, 1,1), strides=(1, 1,1))(x1)

    # ===============================================
    #            Convolution Section 2
    # ===============================================
    x2 = conv_block_3D(x1, 3, [48, 48, 96], stage=2, block='a', strides=(1, 1,1), trainable=True)
    x2 = identity_block_3D(x2, 3, [48, 48, 96], stage=2, block='b', trainable=True)

    # ===============================================
    #            Convolution Section 3
    # ===============================================
    x3 = conv_block_3D(x2, 3, [96, 96, 128], stage=3, block='a', trainable=True)
    x3 = identity_block_3D(x3, 3, [96, 96, 128], stage=3, block='b', trainable=True)
    x3 = identity_block_3D(x3, 3, [96, 96, 128], stage=3, block='c', trainable=True)
    # ===============================================
    #            Convolution Section 4
    # ===============================================
    x4 = conv_block_3D(x3, 3, [128, 128, 512], stage=4, block='a', trainable=True)
    x4 = identity_block_3D(x4, 3, [128, 128, 512], stage=4, block='b', trainable=True)
    x4 = identity_block_3D(x4, 3, [128, 128, 512], stage=4, block='c', trainable=True)
    # ===============================================
    #            Convolution Section 5
    # ===============================================
    x5 = conv_block_3D(x4, 3, [512,512, 2048], stage=5, block='a', trainable=True)
    x5 = identity_block_3D(x5, 3, [512,512, 2048], stage=5, block='b', trainable=True)
    x5 = identity_block_3D(x5, 3, [512,512, 2048], stage=5, block='c', trainable=True)
    y = MaxPooling3D((1, 1,1), strides=(1, 1,1), name='mpool2')(x5)
    return inputs, y
```

and  input is (frame_counter,w,h,rgb=3)

and  it use model.py too.

Comment: You need to provide a minimal code reproducing your problem. It's not easy for one to dig into entire repository to find out what have you done so far.

Comment: Where are you doing batch_size==1?

Comment: in command line we choose it,the yellow  block is what  we  do.and with size =1 it works .

Comment: @Mehraban
your right,but it was not really clear witch part is more related,
please tell me for example witch part should be shown here.

Comment: What part of your code creates the network? how do you load the input and fit model? There are essential code blocks.

Comment: and if there is not a solvable question,please tell me what you guess!!!
thanks a lot